# 301 Redirection between two folder of different domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am in the process of combining two separate websites, because one of this, will be closed shortly.

Now, the domainA.es and domainB.es point to the same server, content and htaccess.
I want to simulate the old URL to new URL, for example:

- If you enter in 
  domainB.es/foo.asp you will be redirect to domainA.es/bar/

<--- Another complication (at least for me) is that the domain A, uses permalinks, and this is the file.

In other words, I need to map the old URL to the new ones.

```
domainB.es/foo.asp --> domainA.es/bar/
domainB.es/something.php--> domainA.es/otherThing/
```

I try use

```
Redirect 301 /foo.asp domainA.es/bar
```

But I can't control fully the original URL (http or https for example) and the finally URL is broken because the name of the file is include at the end of the redirection:

```
domainA.es/bar/foo.asp
```

Probabily, the solution is use RewriteCond and RewriteRule, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainB\.es$
RewriteRule ^foo$ http://domainA.es/bar [L,R,NC]
```

This would redirect http://domainB.es/foo to http://domainA.es/bar

Comment: Works perfectly, and I can investigate the sintax from this example. Thank you very much.